# Components re-render when state changes even if the actual values are the same

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

My **ngrx** state contains an array of items:

```
export interface MyState {
    myItems: ItemType[];
}
```

I have  a component that contains **ngFor** with an async pipe.

*markup*:

```
<app-my-item-details-card *ngFor="let myItem of myItems$ | async"> </app-my-item-details-card>
```

*selector*:

```
this.myItems$ = createSelector(getMyState, state => state.myItems);
```

---

Inside of the AppMyItemDetailsCardComponent I have a boolean flag **displayDetails:boolean** and button **button (click)="displayDetails = !displayDetails"**  that toggles boolean flag. On the details panel I have some inputs that displays some data from **MyItem** instance that is passed to the component. User can modify those html elements and click **Save** button, that fires of an action **MyItemUpdateAction**. In the store reducer I do something like this:

```
const myItemToModifyIndex = state.myItems.findIndex(...predicated based on the passed a ction...)
// cloning the item that I need to modify.
const myItemClone = [...state.myItems[myItemToModifyIndex]];
// modifying properties on the cloned item using data from the action
myItemClone.interestingProperty = action.newValueFromUser;
// cloning the array of items from the state.
const myItemsArrayClone = [...state.myItems];
// setting new item in the cloned array.
myItemsArrayClone[myItemToModifyIndex] = myItemClone;
// return of new state.
return { myItems: myItemsArrayClone }
```

---

**Problem:**

Because as you can see from the reducer that I have modified the state and essentially created a new instances of the **myItems** array and a copy of the item that I have modified, **Angular** **async** pipe reacts to the change in the store and re-renders my list of components. Which in itself re-renders all instances of **AppMyItemDetailsCardComponent** and it causes the flag that displays details of the component to false and UI changes and details panel is hidden.

**Questions:**

1) Does this pattern make sense and fits in with how things are done with NGRX? (I am new to redux in angular).

2) I can resolve this by keeping the flag that displays the details panel inside of the store. Basically instead of toggling **button (click)="displayDetails = !displayDetails"** a boolean flag, I would dispatch an action that would change a flag on an instance of MyItem itself that would drive the display of the details panel. Can this be considered a good solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

redux, ngrx and state handling is all about the references.

if you create a new array reference, angular thinks it's a new list and rerenders everything.

But if you change the reference of the specific item in the array instead, angular will only push the new [item]="myItem" and cause the single my app item card to update.

It's a matter of very carefully creating the new state tree, only updating what is necessary.

I would also put the displayDetails in the item, that way it will keep in sync when you clone the state changes and not get overwritten.